# Generate Docusign envelop without authentication popup

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign within my web app where users will be able to generate the documents to sign with some information from the web app integrated into Docusign document.

For JWT or Auth Code Grant workflows, Docusign needs the user to sign in to Docusign account to be able to generate an access token.
Now each user cannot really sign into Docusign to generate a document. What's he best  way to create Docusign envelops without the end user logging into Docusign account?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If your app's users have DocuSign user accounts,** then use Authorization Code grant flow: the user authenticates with DocuSign and then your app uses the user's access_token.

**If your app's users do not have DocuSign user accounts** (eg the users are your end customers), then:

1. Create a "system user" in your DocuSign account such as "finance@yourcompany.com"
2. Authenticate to DocuSign as the system user and grant consent to the application. See [this blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent) for more.
3. The above steps are ***one time only!***

Then, when your app is used in production:

1. When a user starts to use your application, your application uses the JWT grant flow to impersonate the system user.
2. Via the JWT grant flow, your app now has an access_token that it can use with the DocuSign APIs. Your app can use the access_token to create an envelope, then create a recipient view (embedded signing ceremony)
3. The app's user can sign via the embedded signing ceremony.
4. Remember to cache the access_token for the system user. Continue to re-use the access_token until it is about to expire.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258048/64904) for info on caching the access_token