# Implementing Docusign Authentication using Requests

Tags: python, docusignapi

I'm creating an [Airbyte](https://airbyte.com/) [connector](https://docs.airbyte.com/integrations) for [Docusign's E-signature Rest API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/).

Part of the process of implementing a connector is to write an authentication routine that extends the `AuthBase` class from `requests.auth`.

The issue is that Docusign **does not support refresh tokens** for JWT grants. According to the [docusign documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/):

> The access token granted by JWT Grant expires after one hour, and **no refresh token is provided.** After the token expires, you must generate a new JWT and exchange it for a new access token.
>
> You can reuse most of the old assertion, just modifying the IAT and EXP values and updating the signature, then submit the updated JWT to get a new access token.
> Generally, apps that use JWT should get a new access token about 15 minutes before their existing one expires.

However, all of the examples in the "backend application flow" from this part of the [requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#oauth-2-and-openid-connect-authentication) (which links to [this page](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#oauth-2-and-openid-connect-authentication) in the `requests-authlib` docs) only seem to allow an Auth2 workflow that *includes* a refresh token.

How can I work around this to make it so that, each time a refresh token expires, a new request is made  (with updated IAT EXP, and signature)?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please accept (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh tokens are a feature of the OAuth Authorization Code grant flow.

The Authorization Code grant flow requires a human to authenticate themself. The result is an 8 hour access token and a 30 day refresh token.

To obtain a new access token, either:

- Ask the human to authenticate again
- Or the app can use the refresh token to obtain a new access token. This can be done autonomously by the app, without bothering the human.

**For the JWT grant flow,** there is no human and no refresh token. Instead, the app simply re-runs the JWT grant flow and receive a new 1 hour access token.

When you re-do the JWT flow, create a new JWT (updated IAT, EXP, etc). Sign it with your private key, and send it to DocuSign to obtain a new access token.

The JWT operation is cheap enough to do once per hour per impersonated user. But you must cache the access token and **not** re-do the JWT grant flow for each API call...

### Python authentication libraries

Most authentication libraries for most languages focus on the Authorization Code grant flow since that is the most commonly used OAuth flow.

But as you've pointed out, you're using the JWT flow. This means that you cannot use these libraries. Instead, you will need to roll your own. Good news is that it isn't too hard. Here's my pseudo code:

```
Send_an_API_request(url, request_details, etc):
   access_token = Get_access_token(user_id);
   api_results = send_api_request(access_token, url, request_details, etc)
   return api_results;

Get_access_token(user_id):
    (access_token, expire_time) = database_lookup(user_id);
    # if access_token is about to expire or we don't have one,
    # create a new access_token and store it
    if (
        ((current_time + 10minutes) > expire_time)
        or
        (access_token is null)
       ):
        # Make a new JWT request
        jwt = make_jwt(user_id);
        signed_jwt = sign(jwt, private_key)
        (access_token, expire_sec) = send_jwt_request(signed_jwt)
        database_store (user_id, access_token, current_time + expire_sec)
    return access_token
```

### Added

Re:

> [I need to] extend the AuthBase class from requests.auth

If the app's architecture requires you to extend the AuthBase class, then you will need to implement the JWT grant flow within the AuthBase class.

If the AuthBase class doesn't give you access to the data you need for the JWT grant flow, then a hack is to stuff the needed data into an available attribute such as the "refresh token."